# Uma forma de unificar chamadas em WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

Saudações a todos. Atualmente possuo um WCF Service Application rodando no IIS com muitos serviços, a cada novo serviço criado necessito uma nova atualização e uma nova referencia do lado cliente. Como sou novo em WCF, gostaria de saber se é possível centralizar todos esses serviços em um único serviço? Sei que a pergunta talvez seja muito relativa, pois isso depende muito do que cada método retorna e tal, mas aceito qualquer sugestão, pois queria que existisse apenas um serviço e um método e tudo passasse pelo mesmo canal, é possível? Posso ter perda de solicitações ou é gerado uma fila? Desculpem se não me expressei de uma forma correta ou mais técnica, como disse sou novo, obrigado!

Paulo Balbino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paulo,

Se o objetivo principal for chamar métodos sem atualizar o cliente, seguindo o exemplo, posso te sugerir o seguinte:

```
    enum Metodos { MetodoA, MetodoB };

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMeuServico
    {
        string MetodoA();
        string MetodoB();

        [OperationContract]
        string MetodoPrincipal(Metodos metodo);
    }
```

e a classe que implementa a interface acima:

```
public class Service1 : IMeuServico
{
    public string MetodoA()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public string MetodoB()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public object MetodoPrincipal(Metodos metodo)
    {
        switch (metodo)
        {
            case Metodos.MetodoA: return MetodoA();
            case Metodos.MetodoB: return MetodoB();

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Alexandre, irei implementar seu exemplo para testes.

Answer (score 0):

É possível centralizar todos esses serviços em um único serviço.
Você pode ter um serviço WCF com todos os métodos.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMeuServico
{
    //Disponibilizar todos os métodos que deseja expor no seu serviço
    [OperationContract]
    string MetodoA();

    [OperationContract]
    string MetodoB();
}
```

Porém, se necessário criar um novo método, você continuará precisando atualizar a referência que o cliente tem do seu serviço para que ele possa enxergar esse novo método e utilizar.

**Tente criar serviços baseados em uma funcionalidade.** 
Você vai ter menos código, manutenção mais fácil.

Exemplo:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMeuServicoFuncionalidadeA
{
    //Disponibilizar todos os métodos que deseja expor no seu serviço
    [OperationContract]
    string MetodoA();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMeuServicoFuncionalidadeB
{
    //Disponibilizar todos os métodos que deseja expor no seu serviço
    [OperationContract]
   string MetodoB();
}
```

Sobre: "*...queria que existisse apenas um serviço e um método e 
tudo passasse pelo mesmo canal, é possível? 
Posso ter perda de solicitações ou é gerado uma fila?*"

Com todos os métodos em apenas um serviço pode ser gerada uma fila sim.
Por exemplo, se o modo de gerenciamento de sua instância seja **PerSession** (modo *default*), o serviço conseguirá atender somente uma única *thread* e, sendo assim, as outras *threads* terão que aguardar a liberação para serem processadas.

Para detalhes sobre o gerenciamento de instâncias dê uma olhada nesse [link](http://www.israelaece.com/post/WCF-Gerenciamento-de-Instancias.aspx).

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pela resposta Renan. Minha intenção e ter somente um método dentro de um serviço, preciso fazer de uma forma que o serviço não conheça quem ele está trafegando (lidando), assim não precisaria ficar criando métodos tipados e não teria que atualizar o serviço. Obrigado! Vlw pelo link, vou estudá-lo!